# how to save camera preview frame in video?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I am trying to add a green frame when record a video using android camera like the image below.
I build a custom cameraPreview and apply   `preview.setForeground(getDrawable(R.drawable.frame_green));` in the Camera Activity

After recording a video, this green frame won't show in the video.

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @H.Brooks, after the video saved, this green frame didn't save together with the video, how to save the video with this green frame together?

Comment: This is a very broad question. You will have to decode the video and place the bitmap ontop of the video. I would suggest you look at FFMPEG. Good luck....

Comment: @H.Brooks, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use MediaRecorder to save a video with modified camera stream. You can use MediaCodec to encode modified video (see [CameraToMpegTest sample](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/CameraToMpegTest.java.txt) at http://bigflake.com/mediacodec).

Or you can post-process the video file, as suggested by [H.Brooks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5550161/h-brooks) in [comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47538673/how-to-save-camera-preview-frame-in-video#comment82035574_47538673).